# Draw error bars in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I have created an example scatter plot with five points in MATLAB as follows:

```
x = linspace(0,pi,5);
y = cos(x);
scatter(x,y);
```

In my case, the y-value of each point shall be in a predefined range defined as follows:

```
y_limits = {[0.9 1.1], [0.6 0.8], [-0.1 0.1], [-0.8 -0.6], [-1.1 -0.9]};
```

So for example, the `y` value of point `1` at `x = 0` shall be in the range `[0.9 1.1]`.

I would somehow like to draw five vertical boundaries nicely in the same plot perhaps by means of

- five vertical lines with endpoints at the respective two limits
- five filled vertical areas between the respective two limits
- something else that may be more appropriate

I would like to get some suggestions or sample code of people who are more experienced than me in such kind of graphical representations.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as the `y` value at `x=0` is `y=cos(0)=1`, so definitely not in the range `[0.1, 0.2]`?

Comment: @Wolfie You are right. I just wanted to provide some example data without caring about mathematical correctness. I have adapted the ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one line by using the [`errorbar` function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html)

```
% Your example variables
x = linspace(0,pi,5)';
y = cos(x);
y_limits = [0.9, 1.1; 0.6, 0.8; -0.1, 0.1; -0.8, -0.6; -1.1, -0.9];

% Plot
errorbar(x, y, y - y_limits(:,1), y_limits(:,2) - y, 'x');
% Format: (x, y, negative error, positive error, point style)
```

Result:

[image: error bars]

---

Edit, you can set the line properties of the plot as you call `errorbar`. For example, you could use larger, blue circle markers with thicker, red error bars 
using:

```
errorbar(x, y, y - y_limits(:,1), y_limits(:,2) - y, 'o', 'MarkerSize', 2, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'b', 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 1);
```

Note for these images I'm using `grid on` to add the grid. Second result:

[image: result 2]

Comment: The `errorbar` command throws an exception. There seems to be an issue with the matrix dimenions.

Comment: Apologies, see my edit, I intended to transpose `x` (using an apostrophe) so that `y` is a column vector, and can be subtracted from the columns of `y_limits`.

Comment: I like that one. Is it possible to change the color of the errorbar to red while keeping the crosses blue?

Comment: I figured it out. You may add the following code to your answer: `set(eb, 'Marker', 'o', 'MarkerSize', 10, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'b', 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2)`

Comment: You don't have to use `set`, although that's one way to do it! See my edit, consider marking this as accepted if it does what you needed :)

Comment: Thank's a lot for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a lines is done with the `line` command.

```
for i = 1:length(x)
line([x(i) x(i)], [y_limits{i}]);
end
```

Filled areas can be done with `patch` or `fill`. Some reordering of the limits is necessary so that the order given follows a path around the area to be filled. One nice trick is to use the `alpha` command on those filled areas to create transparency.

```
hold on    
y_corners = reshape([y_limits{:}], 2, length(x)).'; %make an array
y_corners = [y_corners(:,1); flipud(y_corners(:,2))]; %corners follow a path around the shape
fill([x fliplr(x)], y_corners, 'blue');
alpha(0.5);
```